# Expectation of $[Y g(X)]$

Tags: probability, intuition, expectation

Firstly, how do I interpret $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]$. I understand $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is like the most likely outcome of a set of experiments (loosely speaking at least - not really a very maths person)? But $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]$? How do I relate to a real life example?

Then, I know $E[g(X)] = \sum_X g(x) f(x)$ but how do I find $\mathbb E[Y g(X)]$

Why is

$$\mathbb{E} [Y g(X)] = \sum_{(x,y) \in Z} y \, g(x) f(x, y)$$

How do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like we have a random variable $X$ with [probability mass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) $f$.  We also have some function $g$ that maps the range of $X$ to some other real number.

Informally, if $X=x$, we replace it by $g(x)$.  Then we take the expected value.

An simple example where this occurs:  Suppose we had a fair coin with one side labeled $0$ and one side labeled $1$.  Then the expected value of a coin toss would be $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{x \in \mathrm{range}(X)} x f(x)=0 \times \tfrac{1}{2}+1 \times \tfrac{1}{2}=0.5.$$

Now suppose we took the coin, and replaced the labels $0 \mapsto 1$  and $1 \mapsto 2$, that is, we replace $x$ with $g(x)=x+1$.  Now the expected value is $$\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\sum_{x \in \mathrm{range}(X)} g(x) f(x)=\sum_{x \in \mathrm{range}(X)} (x+1) f(x)=1 \times \tfrac{1}{2}+2 \times \tfrac{1}{2}=1.5.$$

---

In the second part of the question, we have an additional random variable $Y$.  Or, equivalently, we have a random variable $(X,Y)$ with probability mass function $f(x,y)$.

So $$\mathbb{E}[Y g(X)]=\sum_{(x,y) \in \mathrm{range}((X,Y))} y g(x) f(x,y).$$

Informally, if $(X,Y)=(x,y)$, we replace it by $y g(x)$.  Then we take the expected value.